# Orchard Module - How to return strongly typed Model rathen than dynamic from Driver

Tags: dynamic, data-annotations, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I created a ContactUs module that sends email when user click on Submit button.

Everything works perfectly. However, I am curious if it is possible to return a strongly typed Model rather than dynamic class.

For example, following is my Drivers\ContactUsDriver.cs Display function:

```
protected override DriverResult Display(ContactUsPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
        return ContentShape("Parts_ContactUs", 
           () => shapeHelper.Parts_ContactUs(
                 Name: part.Name));
}
```

As you can see, above is returning a dynamic Parts_ContactUs.

Now, here's snapshot of my Views\Parts\ContactUs.cshtml:

```
@model dynamic

@using (Html.BeginForm("Send", "ContactUs", new { area = "ContactUs" }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Us</legend>
        <div id="contact-us" class="area">
            @Html.TextBox("Name", "")
        </div>
        <div id="submitArea" class="button">       
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Message">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

As you can see above the View is bound to @model dynamic. As a result, I have to do following

```
@Html.TextBox("Name", "")
```

Is there a way I can bind to Model say ContactUsModel and thus do following instead?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
```

Particularly, I am interested so I can write a jquery validation with DataAnnotation attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly possible. Just provide a desired model type as your **first argument** when creating a shape:

```
protected override DriverResult Display(
    ContactUsPart part, 
    string displayType, 
    dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    return ContentShape("Parts_ContactUs", 
       () => shapeHelper.Parts_ContactUs(typeof(MyClass), Name: part.Name));
}
```

Comment: Side note: be aware that this requires `MyClass` to be inherited from `Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes.Shape` or at least it needs to implement `IShape` **and** when `Name` is an actual property of `MyClass` it will be empty in the view due to the following issue (still an issue in Orchard 1.10.1, had the same difficulties again today): https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/5514